# Github gh-pages file path error

Tags: javascript, html, github

I'm new to using github and I've set up a demo page for my repo using gh-pages. It seems to work except one of my files references one of the other files and its subsequently looking for the wrong path.

My file structure is
index.html
/dist/easyPrint.css
/dist/easyPrint.js

The easyPrint.js file references easyPrint.css . The current code works fine when I work locally (eg it looks for the css file in the dist folder and finds it). But when I view it on GH it looks for the css file in the root folder and fails...

Any tips as to what I've done wrong?

Thanks,
Rowan

PS the repo can be seen at https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint , the error can be seen on the demo page (it wont find the css file)

Comment: I can't see a problem. The demo page looks fine to me.

Comment: Does it look ok when you hit the little print icon, thats when the problem occurs... Thanks

Comment: When you run it locally, where is the code tested? Is it in an index.html file or is it in a file in the dist directory?

Comment: The structure when testing locally is the same, there is a main index file and then a dist folder where the actually js files sit.